# matching user inputs with a textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

my text file:

```
apple, computer pie yellow
strawberry , happy
pink , desk yellow cream
ice, maths happy
```

my code:

```
import random
with open('fruit.txt','r') as f:
    myline =random.choice(f.readlines())
    x = myline.split(",")
    print(x[0].strip() +", "+ ''.join(i[0] 
for i in x[1].strip().split(" ")))
```

it prints randomly, a line form the text file, outputs the word before the comma and the first letter of each word after the comma.
for example the output would be:

```
apple, cpy
```

the user then needs to guess what words are after the comma.. how can i match users input with the correct line in the text file?
help i have no idea.. simplest way possible please!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function `input`

```
import random
with open('fruit.txt','r') as f:
    myline =random.choice(f.readlines())
    x = myline.split(",")
    print(x[0].strip()) 
    answers = x[1].strip().split(" ")))
    user_answer = input("guess a word: ")
    if user_answer in answers:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong!)
```

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in first `print` you need `for i in..` part as well

Comment: hello it says 'answers' is not defined.  help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function input.

```
import random with open('fruit.txt','r') as f:

   myline =random.choice(f.readlines())
   x = myline.split(",")
   print(x[0].strip()) 
   answers = x[1].strip().split(" ")
   user_answer = input("guess a word: ")
   if user_answer in answers:
     print("Correct!")
   else:
     print("Wrong!")
```